# What does this JavaScript code trying to do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came across a block of code in a project and I find it hard to understand:

```js
let isSelected = false;
const results = items.filter(Boolean).map(item => {
  isSelected = !isSelected && id === item.id;
  return {
    id: item.id,
    name: item.name
  };
});
```

What's the line `isSelected = !isSelected && id === item.id;` before the `return` is trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a confusing way of, while mapping through the array, also setting `isSelected` to true if any of the elements in the array match the ID.

An equivalent approach would be

```
const truthyItems = items.filter(Boolean);
const results = truthyItems.map(item => ({
  id: item.id,
  name: item.name
}));
const isSelected = truthyItems.some(item => item.id === id);
```

Side-effects inside a `.map` callback are usually a bit of a code smell.